# Geometry Nodes: How can I make some instanced object disappear when they reach a Z-scale of zero?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a geometry nodes setup that adds instanced cylinders across a circular plane - I'm using a vertex proximity modifier (driving attribute "Displacement") and a sample texture node to control the scaling (driving attribute "Disp") - I'm doing this by mixing between an attribute fill that has a z value of 6 (first attribute in the chain, "scale"), and an attribute fill that has a Z value of c (second attribute in the chain, "scale2"). Right now there is flashing when an instance reaches z scale = 0 because the top and bottom surfaces of the cylinder are fighting between one another. They are also flashing because they are fighting with the surface the the entire geo nodes objects is on top of.

Is there a way to make instances that reach a z scale of 0 to disappear completely? If not, is there a more efficient way to drive the z-scale of the instances, rather than the way I'm doing it (mixing between "scale" and "scale2" attributes, "scale2" having a z scale of 0) Thanks in advance for any advice[image]

Comment: can u please provide blend file, so we do not to rebuild everything?

Comment: @Chris unfortunately I can't because it's loaded with assets that are under NDA.

Comment: well...then exchange the assets with some primitive ones.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, you can.

Use point separate to split points into 2 groups by height:

[image]

Group with 0 height you should not use, second one will have only points with height > 0

Comment: You are a genius!!! Thank you so much @crantisz!!!